# How to account for multiple measure values within a calculation

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am a relatively new to Tableau and use the program mostly as you would a pivot table.

I am trying to combine multiple measures to make order dates readable for clients. E.g. either Monday, Week of 1/4 or Mondays, 1/4-6/15. The final version will have columns with products, order dates, volumes, etc.

However, there are sometimes two receiving days, e.g. Mondays and Thursdays, 1/4-6/15. (Whether it is a one time order or weekly order does NOT have to do with # of receiving days- just for clarification.)

My calculation looks like this. I am not sure how to account for the multiple receiving days:

IF [Order Frequency]= "Recurring Order" THEN [Receiving Day]+"s, " +[Week of (Monday)]+" - "+[End Date]
Else [Receiving Day]+ ", " + "Week of "+[Week of (Monday)] END

I tried writing and subbing a new calculated measure for [Receiving Day] to account for multiple and got this far:
If [Receiving Day]>1 Then **[Receiving Day]+"s and"+[Receiving Day]+"s**, " Else [Receiving Day]+"s, " END

I'm thinking you can't use the measure name back to back like the bolded part to indicate multiple values.

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure there are only a maximum of two receiving days then you could use Level of detail expressions to find the two days.  Without knowing the values its hard to figure out how to give you an example, but I will try:

> IF [Order Frequency]= "Recurring Order"
> THEN { FIXED [Client ID or number]: MIN([Receiving Day]) }+"s, " +[Week of (Monday)]+" - "+{
> FIXED [Client ID or number]: MAX([Receiving Day]) } ELSE [Receiving Day]+ ", " + "Week of "+[Week of (Monday)]
> END

Comment: This worked with FIXED [Week of (Monday)] , thank you! Any idea how to account for if there is only one receiving day (which reads as Wednesdays, Wednesdays) and remove one?

Comment: Actually, FIXED [Client],[Week of (Monday)] worked best